# Insert all remaining dates until a specific date into a slider

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, momentjs, bootstrap-slider

I am using a bootstrap slider for an interest calculator, where I can slide an amount from 0 - 15.000 DKK and another slider that contains remaining days until a specific dates.

Those two slider will calculate the interest when money is inserted at specific dates.

My problem now is that I want the slider tooltip to show sequential dates, i.e at page load the slider will start on todays date (3 March 2016), then when I slide it 4 steps the tooltip should show 7 March 2016, and if I slide it 30 steps it should show 2 April.

The slider is initialised with this:

```
$(".date").slider({
    tooltip: 'always',
    min: 1,
    max: daysRemaining,
    step: 1,
    value: daysRemaining,
    formatter: function (daysRemaining) {
       DateOutputFunction here
     }
 });
```

daysRemaining are found using moment.js

```
var today = moment();
var lastDate = moment("20161212");
var daysRemaining = lastDate.diff(today, "days");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use moment [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) and moment [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to get what you need, for example:

```js
var today = moment();
var lastDate = moment("20161212");
var daysRemaining = lastDate.diff(today, "days");

$(".date").slider({
    tooltip: 'always',
    min: 1,
    max: daysRemaining,
    step: 1,
    value: daysRemaining,
    formatter: function (value) {
        var today = moment();
        var day = today.add(value, "days");
        return day.format("D MMMM YYYY");
    }
 });
```

```css
.slider{
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/6.1.1/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/6.1.1/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css">

<input type="text" class="date">
```